# Getting 401.1 error when calling the web API endpoint with Windows Authentication enabled

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

**Scenario:**
We have an ASP.NET Core web application, as well as ASP.NET Core Web.API service. These are hosted on the same server (Windows 2016), and in the same domain, although under different web sites (we have one for services, and one for applications). This is an intranet type application, and we would like to be able to pass the windows credentials from the client user to the application, and also as part of the API calls.

I have enabled Windows Authentication for the application as well as the service in IIS. I cannot currently get past getting  401.1 when calling the web.api endpoint through the application code. I can browse to the application as well as the api in the web browser though.

**The API code:**

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In ValuesController.cs

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {"value1", "value2" };
    }

}
```

**The application code:**

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);           
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The function call, using RestSharp (although HttpWebRequest also gives 401)

```
private string GetRestResponse(string endpoint)
{
    var client = new RestClient(endpoint);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    return response.Content;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the details IIS web site architecture about the asp.net core and another web sites? Besides , I suggest you could try to use NtlmAuthenticator for spcial user by using RestSharp as below:
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Authenticators/NtlmAuthenticator.cs

Comment: Looks like this may be a DNS configuration issue? After I add code to RunImpersonated, I get errors related to non-authoritative answer.

**Error**
This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server